# Is it possible to parse a zip file without extraction in PHP

Tags: php, webserver, zip

I have 4 questions:

1. Is it possible to scan the entire zip file and navigate inside it without extracting the entire zip using PHP?
2. Will it be time efficient? i.e. I have a zip file of about 50GB which consists many small files(esp. lots of images form past) and I want to use PHP to make a file explorer.
3. Can this be done recursively i.e. if I have many zips inside a big zip, will I be able to parse them?
4. If, I can parse the zip then, does it mean I can open files inside like I can in a normal file browser?

Answer (score 0):

Probably.  A simple google search turned up [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php).  It looks like there is full support for Zip archives.

Comment: Yea, well that's good but, what I am really waiting on is the last two questions

Comment: and now also on the last question

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all. At least if *"scan the entire zip file"* does not mean actually scanning the entire file. If it is small it does not matter, but if it is huge yes.

In short ZIP files are built in a way that makes it possible to list, update, remove, add files without reading the entire file. Also note that originally ZIP was often used to save do disks which could span multiple disks. In other words you can have a zip-file starting on disk#1 and ending on disk#44.

The fact that one do not need disk#1 - disk#28 to extract file 342 on disk#29 also applies if the file is on one disk, but conceptually it is perhaps easier to understand. You do not read file#1 to file#341 to extract file#342.

That aside, in short, a ZIP-archive ends with a Central Directory. This directory holds information about the current state of the zip-archive and is what should be used.

---

## Overall structure

The overall structure of a zip-archive is typically (simplified):

```
Local File Header 1
      File Data   1
      Descriptor  1 (optional) 
Local File Header 2
      File Data   2
      Descriptor  2 (optional)
Local File Header N
      File Data   N
      Descriptor  N (optional)

Central Directory
   Details File 1
   Details File 2
   Details File N
   End Of Central Directory
```

But ZIP-archives *"allow"* for non-archive data as well as deleting and adding entries (Where removing the data is not a requirement).

<sup>Allow is used rather flexible here</sup>

So an archive could be something like this:

```
Local File Header 1
      File Data   1
Local File Header 2
      File Data   2
Non Archive Data    << not part of the archive, but part of the file.
Local File Header 3
      File Data   3
      Descriptor  3
Non Archive Data    << not part of the archive, but part of the file.
Central Directory   << old central directory
   Details File 1
   Details File 2
   End Of Central Directory

Local File Header 4
      File Data   4

Central Directory
   Details File 1
   Details File 3
   Details File 4
   End Of Central Directory
```

Here one have a scenario where data has been added between some of the records, File 2 has been deleted, but the data not removed, File 4 has been added and a new Central Directory written without removing the old.

One can in fact append a zip archive to any existing file and it is still usable.

```
foo.zip
[GIF IMAGE]
[ZIP FILE RECORD]
[LETTER TO MOM]
[ZIP FILE RECORD]
[CENTRAL DIRECTORY]
```

One might call the file a huge mess, but as a ZIP-archive it is still readable. One can argue it is not valid per spec, and willingly ignore it, but that is another story.

Point being:

A proper ZIP-reader uses the last Central Directory. This one should always hold information about the current state of the archive. It gives information about file-name, time, date, compression-method, disk-start, disk-end, number of files, where each file starts and ends, checksum for each file etc.

One can look at a zip-archive as a huge blob of data where the CD say where each file starts and ends ++.

---

## In general

Most zip-archives are of course a lot cleaner then this, but only to give a bit of context.

In short: To get an overview of files in the archive all one need to do is read the CD. By this one can list for example:

```
file1 date size_compressed size_uncompressed
file2 date size_compressed size_uncompressed
file3 date size_compressed size_uncompressed
file4 date size_compressed size_uncompressed
```

The Local File Header can be useful when recovering a corrupted file, or when CD is missing etc. but can also be lacking. It normally holds size of the file data, but not always. If it does not it is typically

```
Local File Header
  ...
  size_compressed: 0
  size_uncompressed: 0
  ...
File Data
Descriptor
   size_compressed: 3214
   size_uncompressed: 6128
```

so you end up with the problem having to guess-read where data starts and ends in case you read file from byte 0.

A typical reason for this is that ZIP can archive streams of data. Thus one do not know the size of the file, nor the checksum, before it is written and the header can as a result not hold this information. Also here remember that a file can span several disks. The size should, however, always be added to CD.

---

As one can read where a file starts and end it is also easy enough to cherry-pick a file. If CD say a file starts at offset 632156 and ends at 952144 then read those bytes and, if compressed, decompress accordingly.

If you have nested files, archives within archives, within archives, ... each archive would need to be looked up their respective CD parsed.

*Side note: **Easy** is relative here of course.*

## End of central directory record

As an archive can span multiple disks, so can the CD. The *End of central directory record* holds information on which disk the CD starts and ends. These days it is usually same disk, but an important note, and easier to understand if one decide to look at the format from specifications.

There is (of course) a lot more to this. All depending on what one want to support. For example can the data be encrypted.

For a full read check out [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

Knowing the basics of how a ZIP archive is built up makes it easier to know what you can do and what not also when using libraries like PHP Zip.

---

## PHP Zip

Have never used it, but from the looks of it it has all the features you need. *Guess* it does not read the file data until asked. Have a look at Example #2 here for example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Test on a big archive and time it. If it only reads CD it should be relatively fast even on huge archives.

---

Have written a ZIP-parser for fun once, but that is an entirely different story hah.